# Anything wrong with this doctype

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, doctype

My WordPress site is having some major IE issues that include jQuery, box-shadow, and other strange CSS problems.

Would my doctype be to blame?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 6]>
<html id="ie6" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html id="ie7" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html id="ie8" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 6) | !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>NA-net | NA&#039;s Communication Network</title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://121.5.7.109/na_comm_new/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven-child/style.css" />
<link rel="pingback" href="http://121.5.7.109/na_comm_new/xmlrpc.php" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://121.5.7.109/na_comm_new/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="NA-net &raquo; Feed" href="http://121.5.7.109/na_comm_new/?feed=rss2" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="NA-net &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://121.5.7.109/na_comm_new/?feed=comments-rss2" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp_sidebarlogin_css_styles-css'  href='http://121.5.7.109/na_comm_new/wp-content/plugins/sidebar-login/style.css?ver=3.4.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bbp-default-bbpress-css'  href='http://121.5.7.109/na_comm_new/wp-content/plugins/bbpress/bbp-theme-compat/css/bbpress.css?ver=2.1.2' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='slider-css'  href='http://121.5.7.109/na_comm_new/wp-content/plugins/easing-slider/css/slider.css?ver=1.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://121.5.7.109/na_comm_new/wp-content/plugins/easing-slider/js/jquery.js?ver=1.4.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://121.5.7.109/na_comm_new/wp-content/plugins/sidebar-login/js/blockui.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
```

Comment: try this doctype once and try <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: I guess it just got cut off in the example, but your last script tag is not closed.

Comment: "Would my doctype be to blame?" - NOP, "Would changing the doctype fix the problems" - NOP, "How would the problems be fixed than" - Isolate each problem, Look with developer tools as to the properties causing the problem, post back with each problem and only revelant code.

Comment: @Jawad Well honestly I am pretty confident that it is just one problem since all of these issues happened at once.

Comment: Ok but what exactly is the problem? "other strange CSS problems" does not give us enough rope to chalk out a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided your code is standards compliant, it is unlikely your doctype is causing the problem. *(Obviously the quick way to check is easy: change it to the HTML4.01 doctype and see if anything corrects itself!)* The 'generic' HTML doctype should trigger standards mode in all modern browsers, and even legacy browsers should switch to full or near standards mode in the presence of *any* doctype. Given you tagged IE9 in the question, your problems are likely due to IE9 being only partially standards compliant past CSS 2.1. I suggest trying to isolate your problems individually.

*Box-shadow:* According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-shadow#Browser_compatibility), you may need to explicitly set `border-collapse:seperate` for it to work in IE.

*Other:* I see you use conditional comments to sniff out IE6-8. Perhaps you need to extend this to IE9? Also watch out for any nasty inline CSS hacks...

Answer (score 1):

Doctype is ok, but i would recommend to use this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 6]>      <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7 lt-ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>         <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7 ie6"> <![endif]-->   
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="lt-ie9 ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="modern"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
...
```